# Execution within Do-While loops, fails to show results after few attempts

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a CUI like application in powershell script. For example, showing around 7 options - each mapped to a numeral character. A prompt is presented, and the admin can type the respective numeral letter to choose an option.

I am using a Do-While loop and Switch statement to accomplish this. For each option, I've made a function with a Exe command and error trapping mechanism.

This script working fine with out any issue, but the problem is the executables I use inside the functions are showing results only 5 or 10 times beore no results are shown, not even an error. This condition continues for all exe files in the same console even after terminating from the script.

If I close the powershell console and open a new one, the executables work fine for 5 to 10 times and issue starts again. I not able to identify what is causing this issue.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#As requested i am posting the entire script
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function Show-HeaderMessage
{
Write-host "" 
Write-host ""
Write-host (" "*10 + (" ___" + ("_" * $Script:PadRight)          + " ")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" ").PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "                     )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("GMOL - New DFS Migration Tool (S Drive)" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)   ) -ForegroundColor "Green"  -NoNewline
Write-host (                             "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "                   )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("---------------------------------------" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)       ) -ForegroundColor "Green"  -NoNewline
Write-host (                   "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" ").PadRight($Script:PadRight)    + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "                     )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("Version : 1.0"              ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)        ) -ForegroundColor "Green"  -NoNewline
Write-host (                    "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "                )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("Date    : $Script:strMDate" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)     ) -ForegroundColor "Green"  -NoNewline
Write-host (                         "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!___" + ("_" * $Script:PadRight)        + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + (" ___" + ("_" * $Script:PadRight)          + " ")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" ").PadRight($Script:PadRight)        + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
#Return $Null
}

Function Show-FooterMessage
{
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" ").PadRight($Script:PadRight)         + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!___" + ("_" * $Script:PadRight)          + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*10 + ("AO_ID").PadRight(20) + " : " + $Script:strMAdmin          ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("Domain Name").PadRight(20) + " : " + $Script:strMDomain     ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("DFS Root").PadRight(20) + " : " + $Script:DFSRoot     ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("DFS Virtual Folder").Padright(20) + " : " + $Script:DFSVF      ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("Target Server").Padright(20) + " : " + $Script:TargetServer      ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("SDDL File Location").Padright(20) + " : " + $Script:SDDLFileFinalPath  ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("CSV  File Path").Padright(20) + " : " + $Script:CSVFileFinalPath    ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("____" + ("_" * $Script:PadRight)    + " ")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
#Return $Null
}

Function Show-MainMenu
{
Clear-Host
Show-HeaderMessage
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("Main Menu"   ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("---------"  ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" "    ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("T. Test DFSRoot Shared_Data"  ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("V. View DFSRoot Shared_Data" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" "      ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("1. Set DFS Virtual-Folder Name" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("2. Set Target Server Name"   ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "                                                                               )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("3. CSV File options"  ).PadRight($Script:PadRight-12)    + "[Sub Menu]  ") -ForegroundColor "cyan" -NoNewline
Write-host (                                                                                             "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "               )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
Write-host (("4. Create DFSLinks"   ).PadRight($Script:PadRight-12)   + "[Sub Menu]  ") -ForegroundColor "cyan" -NoNewline
Write-host (                                                                                             "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   "              )) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"  -NoNewline
Write-host (("5. Configure DFSLink Permissions" ).PadRight($Script:PadRight-12)   + "[Sub Menu]  ") -ForegroundColor "cyan"  -NoNewline
Write-host (                                                                                             "!") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

#Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("7. View CSV file in HTML"  ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor $Color

Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + (" "       ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*10 + ("!   " + ("Q. Quit Application"  ).PadRight($Script:PadRight)  + "!")) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"

Show-FooterMessage
Write-host (" "*10 + "Previous Option      : " + $Script:MMPreviousOption)
Write-host (" "*10 + "Status               : " + $Script:MMPreviousStatus)
Write-host ""
Write-host (" "*10 + "Select Option   : ") -ForegroundColor "Yellow" -NoNewline
}


Function Confirm-option
{
$xkey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
$Option = [CHAR]([int]$xkey.Character)
Return $Option
}

Function Show-PrepareCSVThreadHeader
{
Param
(
$headerOption
)

Write-host ("_____________________________________________________________") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "Prepare CSV Input File"                               ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host (" "*5 + "----------------------"                               ) -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host (" "*5 + $headerOption                                          )
Write-host ("_____________________________________________________________") -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
}

Function Start-PrepareCSVThread
{

Do
{
Show-PrepareCSVMenu
$Script:PCMChar = Read-Host
Switch($Script:PCMChar)
{
'v'
{
Clear-Host
Show-PrepareCSVThreadHeader "Option V : View Target Server Share Folder Details"
$Script:PCMPreviousOption = "V. View Target Server Share Folder Details"
Do_ViewShareFolders
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
1
{
Clear-Host
Show-PrepareCSVThreadHeader "Option 1 : Create CSV Input File"
$Script:PCMPreviousOption = "1. Create CSV Input File"
Do_CreateCSVFile
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
2
{
Clear-Host
Show-PrepareCSVThreadHeader "Option 2 : Set CSV File path"
$Script:PCMPreviousOption = "2. Set CSV File path"
Do_SetCSVFile
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
3
{
Clear-Host
Show-PrepareCSVThreadHeader "Option 3 : View CSV in HTML"
$Script:PCMPreviousOption = "3. View CSV in HTML"
Do_ViewCSVFile
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
Default
{
if($Script:PCMChar -ne 'q')
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : Invalid option")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
}
}
}
}While(($Script:PCMChar -ne 'q') -OR ($Script:PCMChar -ne 'Q'))
}

Function Do_SetTargetServerName
{
param
(
$headerOption
)
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + $headerOption                                        )  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
if($Script:DFSRoot -ne "")
{
Write-Host ""
$TSN = Read-host -Prompt "Enter Target Server name "
Write-Host ""

if($TSN -match "^[a-z]+[\w]+[a-z0-9]+$")
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ("Testing connection to the Target server " + "`"$TSN`"" + ". Please Wait... ")

Write-Host ""
if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $TSN -Quiet)
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Success : Target Server " + "`"$TSN`"" + " is Valid")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host ""
Write-host "Press 'Y' to Set Target Server name..." -NoNewline

if((Confirm-option) -eq 'y')
{
$Script:TargetServer = $TSN
if(Create_Folder ("C:\Hamtramck\SDDL_Files\" + $Script:TargetServer))
{
$Script:SDDLFileFinalPath = "C:\Hamtramck\SDDL_Files\" + $Script:TargetServer
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Target Server     : $Script:TargetServer")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-host ("SDL File Location : $Script:SDDLFileFinalPath")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host ""
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Target Server     : $Script:TargetServer")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-host ("SDL File Location : C:\Hamtramck\SDDL_Files\")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host ""
}
Write-Host ""
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "Set Target Server Name - operation Completed")           -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Completed"
}
Else
{
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host "" 
Write-host (" "*5 + "Set Target Server Name - operation Cancelled")           -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Cancelled"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Failed : Unable to connect to Target Server " + "`"$TSN`"" + ". Test connection Failed")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : Target Server Name " + "`"$TSN`"" + " is not a valid Format")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
}

}

Function Do_SetDFSVirtualFolder
{
param
(
$headerOption
)
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + $headerOption                                        )  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
if($Script:DFSRoot -ne "")
{
Write-Host ""
$Vf = Read-host -Prompt "Enter next DFS virtual folder name "
Write-Host ""
if($VF.Length -eq 9)
{
if($Vf -match "^Group+[0-9]{4}$")
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Success : DFS Virtual Folder Name " + "`"$Vf`"" + " is Valid.")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-host ("Note    : " + "`"$Vf`"" + " will be the virtual folder for DFS links to be created.")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host ""
Write-host "Press 'Y' to Set DFS Virtual Folder..."
if((Confirm-option) -eq 'y')
{
$Script:DFSVF = $Vf
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("DFS Virtual Folder: $Script:DFSVF")  -ForegroundColor "Green"
Write-Host ""
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "Set DFS Virtual-Folder Name operation Completed")      -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Completed"
}
Else
{
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host "" 
Write-host (" "*5 + "Set DFS Virtual-Folder Name operation Cancelled")      -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Cancelled"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : DFS Virtual Folder Name " + "`"$Vf`"" + " have an incorrect format")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : Length of the DFS Virtual Folder Name " + "`"$Vf`"" + "is not correct")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
}

}

Function Do_ViewDFSFolders
{
param
(
$headerOption
)
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + $headerOption                                        )  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
if($Script:DFSRoot -ne "")
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "DFS Root : $Script:DFSRoot" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host "Press 'Y' to Start DFS Enumeration..."
if((Confirm-option) -eq 'y')
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Enumerating Shared_Data DFS Root Folder Structure. Please wait... "
Write-Host ""
$M1optVCMDString1 = "C:\Windows\System32\DFSCMD.EXE"
$M1optVCMDString2 = " /View " +$Script:DFSRoot
$M1optVCMDString =  $M1optVCMDString1 + $M1optVCMDString2
Write-host $M1optVCMDString
Write-Host ""

Invoke-expression "cmd.exe /c `"`"$M1optVCMDString 2>&1`"`""

#DFSCMD.Exe /View $Script:DFSRoot | Sort-object


Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"    -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "View DFSRoot 'Shared_Data' - operation Completed")       -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"    -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Completed"
}
Else
{
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"   -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host "" 
Write-host (" "*5 + "View DFSRoot 'Shared_Data' - operation Cancelled")      -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"   -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Cancelled"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : DFS Root Folder not Set")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
Return $Null

}

Function Do_TestDFSRoot
{
param
(
$headerOption
)
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + $headerOption                                        )  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
if($Script:DFSRoot -ne "")
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "DFS Root : $Script:DFSRoot" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host "Press 'Y' to Begin Testing..."
if((Confirm-option) -eq 'y')
{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Initiating DFSRoot Testing. Please wait... "
Write-Host ""
$M1optTCMDString1 = "C:\Windows\System32\DFSDIAG.EXE /TestDFSConfig"
$M1optTCMDString2 = " /DFSRoot:" + $Script:DFSRoot
$M1optTCMDString =  $M1optTCMDString1 + $M1optTCMDString2

Invoke-Expression $M1optTCMDString

Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "Testing DFSRoot 'Shared_Root' - operation Completed")  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Completed"
}
Else
{
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*5 + "Testing DFSRoot 'Shared_Root' - operation Cancelled")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-host "_____________________________________________________________"  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Cancelled"
}
}
Else
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host ("Error : DFS Root Folder not Set")  -ForegroundColor "Red"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""
$Script:MMPreviousStatus = "Error"
}
}


Function Start-Application
{
$Script:strMDate = (Get-Date).ToLongDateString() + " " + (Get-Date).ToLongTimeString()
$Script:strMAdmin = Get-content env:UserName
$Script:strMDomain = Get-Content env:UserDNSDomain
$Script:TargetServer = ""
$Script:DFSVF = ""
$Script:EnteredOption = 0
$Script:PadRight = 70
if($Script:strMDomain -ne "")
{
$Script:DFSRoot = "\\" + $Script:strMDomain + "\" + "Shared_Data"
Do
{
Show-MainMenu
$Script:MMChar = Read-Host
Switch($Script:MMChar)
{
't'
{
Clear-Host
$Script:MMPreviousOption = "T. Test DFSRoot 'Shared_Data'"
Do_TestDFSRoot "Main Menu :: T. Test DFSRoot 'Shared_Data'"
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine                    
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
'v'
{
Clear-Host
$Script:MMPreviousOption = "V. View DFSRoot 'Shared_Data'"
Do_ViewDFSFolders "Main Menu :: V. View DFSRoot 'Shared_Data'"
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
1
{
Clear-Host
$Script:MMPreviousOption = "1. Set DFS Virtual-Folder Name"
Do_SetDFSVirtualFolder "Main Menu :: 1. Set DFS Virtual-Folder Name"
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
2
{
Clear-Host
$Script:MMPreviousOption = "2. Set Target Server Name"
Do_SetTargetServerName "Main Menu :: 2. Set Target Server Name"
Write-host "Press any key..." -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
3
{
Start-PrepareCSVThread
}
4
{
Start-CreateDFSLinkThread
}
5
{
Start-ACLConfigThread
}
'q'
{
Clear-History
Clear-Host
}
Default
{
if(($Script:MMChar -ne 'q') -OR ($Script:MMChar -ne 'Q'))
{
Write-Host ""
Write-host (" "*10 + "Error : Invalid option. Press any key...")  -ForegroundColor "Red" -NoNewLine
$dummykey = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
}
}
}
}While(($Script:MMChar -ne 'q') -OR ($Script:MMChar -ne 'Q'))
}
Else
{
Write-host "Application Failed : Unable to Identify Local Domain"
Write-host ""

}
}

Start-Application
```

Comment: Can you post the entire script, with all the options? It doesn't look like the problem is in the part you posted here. Is this happening regardless of which options you select, or only after you select particular options (not necessarily immediately after you select those options)?

Comment: Hi, I was unable to post the complete script, since the character count is beyond the limit accepted by this forum portal.

Comment: Still i have uploaded all the script portions which will invoked at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script on my Win7 machine. I don't have DFSCMD.EXE present so I got an error everytime the script executed it. Other than that the script ran 30+ times with no hint of trouble.

I suggest commenting out the invoke expression of DFSCMD.EXE and see how it works then. If it works consistently I would add it back in, and then watch Powershell and the overall system performance in task manager as you go through the 5-10 invocations. Under Powershell I'd look for memory usage, handles, and threads. I would expect some memory usage increase in Powershell, but not huge, and it should creep back down if PS is left idle. Also each instance of DFSCMD.EXE should disappear from taskmgr after you exit it.

You could also use Process Explorer and get more in depth. For example procexp will let you look at a process's threads' stacks. Once you get to the "not working state", you might be able to get a hint as to what's going on by looking through PS's threads. You need to load symbols to get procexp to show symbols on the stack. I think procexp's help tell you how to do that.

Beyond that I'd break out a debugger ... Let the good times roll

Comment: hi, We need dfscmd.exe to be present to reproduce this problem. It is not mandatory that only DFSCMD.exe should be used. You can replace it with Ping.exe with relevent option and run the script. I have posted the major portion of script which contains all options. In that you have to select option V continously again and again to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Did you look at taskmgr and/or procexp as suggested? Did you see anything of interest?

Comment: I tried with PING.exe about 30 times - no hint of instability. You'll to do some work and better characterize this problem and post back what you tried.